# How to check for empty cells in range if empty then check in selection VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that will filter the table by the user `selection`.

1. I would like to first check `range A3:T3` if they have values in and if they do i will add to my array and start filtering by that and ignore all empty cells in `Range A3:T3`.
2. If range A3:T3 is empty then filter by user `selection`.
3. I notice there is a bug where if i filter by a cell and that cell has 2 rows with data 1 will show and 1 not because there is a space in front of it i think its a `ChrW` is there any way to make the filter take partial match to include both versions? I know i can replace the `ChrW` and replace it but data will be always pasted from outlook so the occurrence will be frequent so if i can take a partial match that will probably solve a lot of the problems.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub advancedMultipleCriteriaFilter()

  Dim cellRng As Range, tableObject As Range, subSelection As Range
  Dim filterCriteria() As String, filterFields() As Integer
  Dim i As Integer

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  'Call removeSpace  

  If Selection.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Cannot apply filter to multiple rows within the same column. Please make another selection and try again.", vbInformation, "Selection Error!"
    Exit Sub
  End If

  i = 1
  ReDim filterCriteria(1 To Selection.Cells.Count) As String
  ReDim filterFields(1 To Selection.Cells.Count) As Integer

  Set tableObject = Selection.CurrentRegion
  For Each subSelection In Selection.Areas
    For Each cellRng In subSelection
      filterCriteria(i) = cellRng.Text
      filterFields(i) = cellRng.Column - tableObject.Cells(1, 1).Column + 1
      i = i + 1
    Next cellRng
  Next subSelection

  With tableObject
    For i = 1 To UBound(filterCriteria)
      .AutoFilter field:=filterFields(i), Criteria1:=filterCriteria(i)
    Next i
  End With

  Call GetLastRow

  Set tableObject = Nothing
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Sub resetFilters()

  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Dim LastRow As Range

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  On Error Resume Next
  If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
  End If

  Range("A3:T3").ClearContents
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Call GetLastRow

End Sub


Private Sub GetLastRow()

  'Step 1: Declare Your Variables.
  Dim LastRow As Long

  'Step 2: Capture the last used row number.
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

  'Step 3: Select the next row down
  Cells(LastRow, 8).Offset(1, 0).Select

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter multi-criteria in a single field, you will need array as below:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("val 2", "val 3", "val 4"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

so filterCriteria(i) must be an Array, you can just do it as below:

```
filterCriteria(i) = Array("item1","item2")
.AutoFilter Field:=filterFields(i), Criteria1:=filterCriteria(i), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.